# How to change text in "span" that is immediately after "i" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, nextsibling

I'm trying to change the text on a button in a plugin I am using using jquery.
It's outer html is

```
<button value="[[3,1,1488182400]]" data-group="2017-02-27" class="ab-hour">
  <span class="ladda-label">
    <i class="ab-hour-icon">
      <span></span>
    </i>8:00 am
  </span>
</button>
```

It's inner html is

```
<span class="ladda-label">
  <i class="ab-hour-icon">
    <span></span>
  </i>8:00 am
</span>
```

Anyone know how I'd change `8:00AM` to `9-3AM`?

Comment: Please provide the html and jquery code

Comment: Hi brent, i edited the initial post to show, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: `$("#ButtonName").text("The new text");`

Comment: What would be the button name in this case? I am very new to jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) that contain immediately text after element.

```
$(".ab-hour .ab-hour-icon")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "9-3AM";
```

```js
$(".ab-hour .ab-hour-icon")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "9-3AM";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="[[3,1,1488182400]]" data-group="2017-02-27" class="ab-hour"><span class="ladda-label"><i class="ab-hour-icon"><span></span></i>8:00 am</span></button>
```

Also you use only javascript

```
document.querySelector(".ab-hour .ab-hour-icon").nextSibling.nodeValue = "9-3AM";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
$( "yourbutton" ).html('yourtext');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(".ladda-label").html("<i class=\"ab-hour-icon\"></i>9-3 am");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="[[3,1,1488182400]]" data-group="2017-02-27" class="ab-hour">
<span class="ladda-label">
<i class="ab-hour-icon">
</i>8:00 am</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work, added into the custom js on the backend but no change.

The button i am referring to is on this link:

http://www.lapelsdrycleaners.co.uk/order-online/

When selecting suits, 2 piece executive, it brings to a page with lots of buttons. I am trying to change the text on the 8AM one and will apply it to all the rest. Thank you for your quick response Sallu!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
$( ".ab-hour span" ).html('9-3AM');
```

It would be best to change the inner HTML so the span can directly be changed. If that is not an option you could use

```
$( ".ab-hour span" ).html('<i class="ab-hour-icon"><span></span></i>9-3AM');
```

Comment: Gus, thank you for the quick response. The buttons i am referring to are here : http://www.lapelsdrycleaners.co.uk/order-online/ after you select any item and click next. I am using a front end global javascript editor - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to add `<span>` in jquery code so your icon will remain

```js
$(".ab-hour").html('<span class="ladda-label"><i class="ab-hour-icon"><span></span></i>9-3AM</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="[[3,1,1488182400]]" data-group="2017-02-27" class="ab-hour">
<span class="ladda-label">
<i class="ab-hour-icon">
</i>8:00 am</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Bhavin, I am using the edit global javascript function on x theme, does this matter?

The button i am referring to is on this link: lapelsdrycleaners.co.uk/order-online When selecting suits, 2 piece executive, it brings to a page with lots of buttons. I am trying to change the text on the 8AM one and will apply it to all the rest. Thank you buddy

Comment: i can see button in footer you can tell about this?